Flutter: Connection closed while receiving data only in emulator
I'm getting the error "Connection closed while receiving data" when trying to make a request (via Dio and HTTP), when the response is larger than 400kb. If it is smaller it works normally.
On the physical device it works normally, regardless of the size of the response.
I have already disabled the emulator proxy
I've already tried it on the Pixel 3, Pixel 6 and Nexus 5X emulators
With API 30 and 31
It all gives the same error
Note: local server in python
Can anyone help me?
